# multi text over image using php

Tags: php, mysql

Good day everyone!

I have this image

[image]

which is called "2.png" and also have a web app that is connected to mysql server and customers can search their data with their policy number.

What I am trying to do is when someone search with his policy number, his data will appear in the exact position as the white spaces are shown over the picture as a real customer card.

I tried everything I found but failed.

(*the data will be called as the picture shown : Name - ID - policy number - Date - Exp* ). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "real customer card" (?) is a picture you have to place absolute values position using CSS to your HTML data filled by your PHP script.

CSS:

```
#form-data-1 {
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
/* and so on.. */
}
```

HTML / PHP

```
<span id="form-data-1"><?php echo $foo ?></span>
```

If you want to write bytes to the picture, use GDI.

Comment: where is the x and y values to make the result appear in the white spaces and how can i add the pic to my web

Comment: Like left: 100px; bottom -20px; This only works if you make an HTML page that contains the CSS used for positioning and your data. You can also use JavaScript to write a page. The image should be inside a <img> tag.